# how can i get the all data from postgresql thats from the current day, between the hours of 00:00:00 and 11:59:59?

Tags: postgresql, epoch, date-arithmetic

very new to the backend as well as all things postgresql, at the moment all ive been able to do is

```
SELECT * FROM nutrition WHERE timestamp >= (extract(epoch from now())::bigint * 1000) - 86400000 AND timestamp <= (extract(epoch from now())::bigint * 1000) + 86400000
```

in the frontend using js, im using Date.now() to store the timestamp in the DB.

timestamp is a column in my db thats logging the unix time in bigint format in which the food was logged. I want to get all the data from the current day from the hours beteen 12 AM midnight, and 11:59 PM. thanks.

for example, the last item i logged was last night at 10pm (1663995295337 UNIX time) so the data shouldnt include it.

show timezone returns;

America/Los_Angeles

Solution below --------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 const today = new Date();
  const beginningOfDay = today.setUTCHours(7, 0, 0, 0);
  const endOfDay = today.setUTCHours(30, 59, 59, 99);

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const text = `
    select 
     * 
    from 
       nutrition 
    where 
      timestamp 
    between ${beginningOfDay} and ${endOfDay}`
```

this was the solution i was looking for, thanks for the help. sorry if i wasnt descriptive enough.

Comment: Is `11:59:59` "high noon" or "midnight" (`23:59:59`)

Comment: I provided a quick and dirty solution as an answer below. It skips over the `timezone` issue though. Are you working in a consistent `timezone`? Also your life would be easier if the timestamps where stored in a `timestamptz` field.

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: 1) Do not use images for textual information per [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). 2) A single value without context is not a sample data set. You need to provide a sample set with information about how it was produced. I'm guessing this is coming from a Web front end via Javascript. I'm also going to say there is a `timezone` difference between the Web front and the database. You will need to provide more information on the process.

Comment: You still have not indicated what `show timezone;` returns in your database.

Comment: That is the solution for ~half a year. What happens when the Fall fall back happens? Again the proper solution is to use a proper field type to hold the data and in this case that is `timestamptz` per [DateTime types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). And using `today.toISOString() "2022-09-24T19:44:48.493Z"` which becomes `select '2022-09-24T19:44:48.493Z'::timestamptz  09/24/2022 12:44:48.493 PDT`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by Unix time you mean `epoch`.

```
select extract(epoch from now());
      extract      
-------------------
 1664038032.392004

 select to_timestamp(1664038032.392004);
          to_timestamp          
--------------------------------
 09/24/2022 09:47:12.392004 PDT


select 
 * 
from 
   some_table 
where 
   to_timestamp(1664038032.392004) 
between 
    current_date + '00:00:00'::time AND current_date + '23:59:59'::time
```

**UPDATE**

Using `timestamptz` field in Postgres and an ISO datetime string from Javascript in order to properly deal with time zone.

```
create table tsz_test(id integer, tsz_fld timestamptz);

--In Web frontend today = new Date().toISOString(); "2022-09-24T20:57:05.830Z"


insert into 
    tsz_test 
values (1, '2022-09-24T20:57:05.830Z'), (2, '2022-09-25T08:57:05.830Z');

select * from tsz_test ;
 id |          tsz_fld           
----+----------------------------
  1 | 09/24/2022 13:57:05.83 PDT
  2 | 09/25/2022 01:57:05.83 PDT

--Borrowing from @a_horse_with_no_name answer
select * from tsz_test where tsz_fld::date = '09/24/2022'::date;
 id |          tsz_fld           
----+----------------------------
  1 | 09/24/2022 13:57:05.83 PDT
```

Comment: this works but it is still returning me data from 12 hours ago, my last logged data was from 10pm yesterday. how can i only get the data from not the last 24 hours  but from 00:00:00 and 11:59:59 of the current day if that makes sense, thanks

Comment: In your question you will need to provide some sample input data and expected output. Also address the timezone issue I brought up in my comments. Also  
@a_horse_with_no_name question about whether you are looking for Noon or Midnight as the end point of the range?

Comment: midnight as endpoint of the range, also in terms of input data and expected output. i have a column in postgres named timestamp thats data type is bigint. im using Date.now() to get the unix time that i logged the food. Not sure what to do about the time zones.

Comment: Add information as update to question, not in comments. Also supply sample data as requested. While you are at add the result of `show timezone;` in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your "unix timestamp" to a date, then compare it with "today":

```
where to_timestamp("timestamp")::date = current_date
```

This assumes that your column named `"timestamp"` is not really a `timestamp`

If the column doesn't actually store seconds (which would be a unix epoch), but milliseconds you need `to_timestamp("timestamp"/1000)::date` instead (another source of problems that wouldn't exist if you had used a proper `timestamptz` or at least `timestamp` data type).

Comment: the column named timestamp is a unix time that i logged the data.

Comment: @Keenan: a unix time in seconds or milliseconds?